# Can a trait have a supertrait that is parameterized by a generic?

Tags: types, rust, higher-kinded-types

Can you do something like this in Rust?

```
trait A : forall<T> B<T> { ... }
```

That is, if we want:

```
impl A for D { ... }
```

We must first implement:

```
impl<T> B<T> for D { ... }
```

Comment: You might want to provide a more concrete use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Rust's type system doesn't currently support any features involving higher kinded types. It does, however, support a similar construction to what you described, but limited to lifetime parameters. For example:

```
trait B<'a> {}

trait A: for<'a> B<'a> {}

struct D;

impl A for D { }
```

This is an error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'a> D: B<'a>` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:7:6
  |
7 | impl A for D { }
  |      ^ the trait `for<'a> B<'a>` is not implemented for `D`
```

Until you add the blanket implementation:

```
impl<'a> B<'a> for D { }
```

---

It's not impossible that Rust will eventually add similar functionality for types too, but I wouldn't expect it any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

While the language is unable to specify such a higher kinded constraint, it is often possible to rethink the trait `B` so that its implementation is universal over this parameter type `T`.

Considering this example of `B`:

```rust
trait B<T> {
    fn foo(bar: T) -> u32;
}
```

A type that implements `B` for any `T` would be practically equivalent to the type implementing the trait below:

```rust
trait UniversalB {
    fn foo<T>(bar: T) -> u32;
}
```

This one declares the type parameters at method call level. While this trait is no longer object safe, it can still be used as a supertrait:

```rust
trait A: UniversalB {}
```

The implementations may need to be adjusted accordingly.

See also:

- The Rust Programming Language, [Chapter 10, Section 1 on *Generic Data Types In Method Definitions*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-01-syntax.html#in-method-definitions)