# Generic supertrait / requiring blanket impl

Tags: generics, rust, traits

Currently, I have a trait like this:

```rust
trait Trait
where
    Self: Sized,
{
    fn try_form_u8(num: u8) -> Option<Self>;
    fn try_from_str<T: AsRef<str>>(s: &T) -> Option<Self>;
    // ...
}
```

Optimally, I want to define it like simliar to this, in order to not have `try_from_*` methods outside of a `TryFrom` implementation:

```rust
trait Trait: for<T: AsRef<str>> TryFrom<u8> + TryFrom<T>
where
    Self: Sized
{
    // ...
}
```

I couldn't find a way to accomplish that and finally came across this thread: [Can a trait have a supertrait that is parameterized by a generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329170/can-a-trait-have-a-supertrait-that-is-parameterized-by-a-generic)

I wonder how to continue from here. Should I use the unconventional `try_from_str` method or is there a better way to express what is needed here?

Note that in my original code I have `Path` instead of `str`, which could eliminate some special solutions, but I would still like to know them if there are any nice solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a type implements `TryFrom<&str>`, it is trivial to create it from a `String` or `Rc<str>` or anything else that is `AsRef<str>`. So let's start with that:

```
trait Trait: TryFrom<u8> + for<'a> TryFrom<&'a str> {}
```

It's easy to use this with other types simply by calling `.as_ref()`, but if you still want the generic version, you can provide a default implementation:

```
trait Trait: TryFrom<u8> + for<'a> TryFrom<&'a str> {
    fn try_from_str<S: AsRef<str>>(arg: &S) -> Result<Self, <Self as TryFrom<&str>>::Error> {
        arg.as_ref().try_into()
    }
}
```

This way, implementors of `Trait` don't have to write anything special, but users still have the convenient `try_from_str` function.

### `Path` version

```
trait Trait: TryFrom<u8> + for<'a> TryFrom<&'a Path> {
    fn try_from_path<P: AsRef<Path>>(arg: &P) -> Result<Self, <Self as TryFrom<&Path>>::Error> {
        arg.as_ref().try_into()
    }
}
```

### `str` version

For `str` specifically, you might want to use the standard library trait `FromStr` instead of `TryFrom`, which is more specialized to this use case, enables `str::parse` and does not require a higher-ranked trait bound:

```
trait Trait: TryFrom<u8> + FromStr {
    fn try_from_str<S: AsRef<str>>(arg: &S) -> Result<Self, <Self as FromStr>::Err> {
        arg.as_ref().parse()
    }
}
```

Comment: You make a good point, moving the conversion to `&str` to the calling code is probably what I am going to do. Do you know if there is a `FromStr` like pattern / convention for `&Path`? And what do you think would be more idiomatic: Having the 'try_from_str` method that is generic or having the `TryFrom<&str>` bound (let's also say that there is no impl for that right now)?

Comment: @Niklas Oh, sorry, I read the paragraph where you said you were using `Path` and then immediately forgot it. No, there's no `FromPath` equivalent, and it's not likely to be added because `TryFrom<&Path>` checks most of the same boxes (`FromStr` was in the standard library before `TryFrom` existed, or maybe we wouldn't have that, either.)